# How can I report a bug for two packages?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting, ubuntu-bug

How can I make reports to several packages such as `unity-2d` and `thunderbird` for a bug with using Thunderbird in Unity 2D?

When I type `ubuntu-bug-report <package>` it only lets me type in one!

Comment: I do not understand your question, sorry. Can you try to explain it more clearly? Do you want to know, why you are asked for permission sending the report only once? If so: sudo is the reason for asking for permission and sudo usually "keeps the permission for a while" and does not ask every time.

Comment: sorry my English is low and use a translator.
My question is how to report multiple bactrace package and include it in the same bug on launchpad

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/562027 an example is shown in LibreOffice bug is affecting more packages than just LibreOffice
In that case can be reported as a bug with multiple backtrace

Comment: a bug is usually filed against one package.You should file a bug report for each problem which occurs.The experts might ask you for further help.But maybe you should ask somewhere in a forum for a solution, as it might not be a bug, just a problem with your configuration? A bug report should only be filed if you are sure it is a bug and not only a problem with your configuration.

Comment: can you maybe edit your question and ask us? can you describe more precisely what happens when thunderbird hangs? can you add log file lines and run thunderbird from a console and post any error messages occuring (type thunderbird in e.g. gnome-terminal)? Finally can you try other window managers whether the problem exists there as well (e.g. gnome classical?) Last thing: can you run the command metacity --replace and try it again then? This will disable compiz for this session (not permanently) and thus disable effects etc. Maybe also a photo of the screen helps.

Comment: ok thank you very much, if I have it very clear that I try not to report false bugs, I have very read what is not a bug and what if.
thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is recommended you use `ubuntu-bug` for reporting bugs. [Instructions for using it are here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

`ubuntu-bug`, the command-line tool, [currently only accepts one package at a time](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/667369). You should try your best to guess what the most relevant one is. In order to add more packages to a bug report after sending, go to its [Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net) and click "Also affects project".

[image: Screenshot of "Also affects project" location on the bug screen]